# Increasing VHD Size in Hyper-V 2008 R2

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V box which is hosting 5 virtual servers.

One of the servers on the Host is currently low on disk space. I am planning to increase the VHD space on that virtual server but I am wondering **how to do so** (?) and I am also wondering **where the extra VHD space comes from**?

Does the extra VHD space come from the Host? If so, will the size of the Host decrease and the size of the server increase?

Lastly, I have 2 drives on my Host.

- C:\ has 132 GB total and 57 GB free
- D:\ has 1396 GB total and 230 GB free

Is it possible to take 50 GB from D:\ and place it into my server which is low on space?

I'm new to Hyper-V so I'm just trying to get my head around things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space for the VHD comes from the host. VHDs are just files afterall, so as more space is consumed by the VHD, less is available on the physical disk that contains it.

As far as using space on your D: drive, there is no option to choose which physical drive the new space comes from. You will need to put the VHD file on that drive and then expand it.

You cannot expand a VHD if there are snapshots associated with it.

[image]

The procedure...

With the VM powered off, open the Settings for the VM. Select the hard drive to be expanded, and click the Edit button.

[image: Edit button for hard drives]

Choose the option to Expand the disk.

[image: selecting the Expand option]

Enter a new size for the disk, and Finish the wizard.

[image: specifying a new disk size]

Do not forget, once you expand the disk, you still need to start Windows, open the Disk Management console, and extend the volume so that it consumes the new space. Windows will not automatically expand the volume for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank for the quick response. So if space is being taken from the Host, how do I determine how much space I can take from the Host? Is it from how much free space is available on the C:\ drive of the Host?

Comment: Yes.  Well, almost.   You don't really want to use up 100% of the space on a drive, and especially not the C:, because Microsoft Windows likes wiggle room.  (The exact amount that should remain free may vary with different versions of Microsoft Windows.)  However, the basic answer to your comment's first question is what you proposed by your comments second question.  If you have "lots" of space available (which is an imprecise amount, as an exact amount that is "lots" will fluctuate over time), you can use that space for a purpose like storing data for a VHD file.

Comment: Ahhhhh I love SuperUser and the super users that use SuperUser! Thank you @TOOGAM for the response. What I will do is take about 25GB of space from my Hosts' C:\ drive and place it in the Virtual Server. And that will leave about 20+GB of free space on the Hosts C:\ drive (which should be plenty I believe). I'll be using Patrick S. 's examples above to achieve this. Thank you both!! :)